# Which lifecycle event to use to read first item

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React component that displays a list of NBA teams and information about them.

I created a TeamsList component that sits on the left and provides a list of teams. I then have a TeamInfo component that provides information about "selected" team.

At the entry point which is the parent to MyMainComponent, I read teams list and put it into my redux store.

Here's what I'm trying to figure out: I want to automatically make an API call to get the information about the first team in the list. Which life cycle event should I use for this in the MyMainComponent e.g. ComponentWillMount, ComponentDidMount or even the constructor?

```
class MyMainComponent extends Component {

   render() {

      const teams = this.props.teamsList;
      const team = this.props.team;

      return(

         <div>
            <div class="leftColumn">
               <TeamsList data={teams} />
            </div>
            <div class="rightColumn">
               <TeamInfo data={team} />
            </div>
         </div>

      );

   }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        teamsList: state.teamsList,
        team: state.team
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyMainComponent)
```

UPDATE:
I'm now handling this in my actions using the code below but for some reason I'm not able to save the first team in my state. I set the initial state for the team to an empty object. I go through my actions/reducer to update the state but for some reason, I keep getting an empty object for the team even though teamsList has the correct data in it. To clarify what I'm doing, at the entry point, I simply call the getTeamsList() function and that automatically calls the getTeam() function. I know this is working fine. I also know that I'm hitting my reducer to update the state both for the teamsList and team.

```
export const setTeamsList = (teams) => {
    return { 
        type: types.SET_TEAMS_LIST,
        teams
    };
}

export const setTeamInfo = (team) => {
    return { 
        type: types.SET_TEAM_INFO,
        team
    };
}
export const setIsLoading = (value) => {
   return{
      type: types.SET_IS_LOADING,
      value
   };
}

export const getTeamsList = () => {

    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch('/api/teams', fetchOptionsGet())
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then(teams => {
            dispatch(setTeamsList(teams))
            dispatch(setIsLoading(true))
            if(teams !== null && teams.length > 0)
                return dispatch(getTeam(teams[0].teamId))
        })
        .then(() => dispatch(setIsLoading(false)))
    };
}


export const getTeam = (id) => {

    return (dispatch) => {

        fetch('/api/team/' + id, fetchOptionsGet())
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then(team => {
            dispatch(setTeamInfo(team))
        })
    };
}
```

And here's my reducer:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    teamsList: [],
    team: {}
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case types.SET_TEAMS_LIST : 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                teamsList: action.teams
            })

        case types.SET_TEAM_INFO : 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                team: action.team
            })

        case types.SET_IS_LOADING:
           return Object.assign({}, state, {
              value: action.value
           })

        default: return state
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:
Looks like the sequence of actions being executed is not what the way I need them. I thought I could control the sequence by wrapping them in another function and run then synchronously but that's not working either.

If you look at the initTeams function that I call to get things going, looks like setIsLoading steps are executing first -- literally back to back. I see that the code is hitting the reducer to set isLoading to true first, then it immediatelly sets it to false. It then executes getTeamsList(). From there it actually goes into the render function of TeamInfo component. After all this, it hits the getTeam() function to load the first team into the store.

UPDATE 3:
Almost there but still need clarification. I now better understand thunks. The one thing that's still confusing me is this: I updated my getTeamsList() function and I expected it to execute actions in the following order:

1. Make API call to get teams list
2. Set Teams List in store
3. Set isLoading to True in store
4. If I have teams, call the getTeam() action to get team info
5. Set team info in store
6. Set isLoading to False

Instead, it executes step 6 right after step 3 then 4 and 5.

Ultimately, I get the results that I want but I want to understand how I can get it to execute steps in the correct order as I want them to be executed.

Comment: do you have SSR (Server-Side Rendering)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using **Redux**, I recommend you to **delegate the task of API calls to your action creators and dispatch them from a Higher Order Component (HOC)**.

I believe components should be agnostic to business logic and API datas. They should only represent the **View** in our MVC apps. [see WHY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711359/changing-the-layout-of-a-component-depending-on-redux-state/40711713#40711713)

See this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731474/render-component-after-action-dispatch/40732960#40732960) where I am explaining how to use `async-connect` from [**`redux-connect`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-connect) for loading the initial data of our App.

---

If you insist to make the API call inside you component itself, do that in **`componentDidMount`**.

Quoting another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139366/why-do-the-react-docs-recommend-doing-ajax-in-componentdidmount-not-componentwi):

> `componentDidMount` is for side effects. Adding event listeners, AJAX,
>   mutating the DOM, etc.
>
> `componentWillMount` is rarely useful; especially if you care about
>   server side rendering (adding event listeners causes errors and leaks,
>   and lots of other stuff that can go wrong).
>
> There is talk about removing `componentWillMount` from class
>   components since it serves the same purpose as the `constructor`. It
>   will remain on `createClass` components.

Component rendering may get delayed when you're using `componentWillMount` for API calls (a common use case we fetch data to `setState` and that will be used to show in the view).

Another issue:

> `componentWillMount` is run on the server, but `componentWillUnmount`
>   (where you remove listeners) isn't. This would cause you to add
>   listeners and never clean them up.

---

#### UPDATE

Regarding the wrong sequence of calling actions:

`getTeamsList` and `getTeam` should be [async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html), basically they should `return` a promise.

The returned promise controlls `.then` attached to the promise chain. So if you miss it, you won't be able to predict the sequence.

We are missing `return`s here:

```
export const getTeamsList = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch('/api/teams', fetchOptionsGet())   ----> missing 'return' before 'fetch'
        // ...
    };
}


export const getTeam = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch('/api/team/' + id, fetchOptionsGet())   ----> missing 'return' before 'fetch'
        // ...
    };
}
```

Since we're using Arrow Function, we don't necessarily need a `return`, instead we can do this (removing the curly braces {}):

```
export const getTeamsList = () => {
    return (dispatch) => fetch('/api/teams', fetchOptionsGet())
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then(teams => {
            dispatch(setTeamsList(teams))
            dispatch(setIsLoading(true))
            if(teams !== null && teams.length > 0)
                return dispatch(getTeam(teams[0].teamId))
        })
        .then(() => dispatch(setIsLoading(false)))
}


export const getTeam = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => fetch('/api/team/' + id, fetchOptionsGet())
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then(team => {
            dispatch(setTeamInfo(team))
        })
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response and I agree with your suggestion. I implemented it but for some reason even though I'm able to commit teamsList to my store, I can't seem to store the first team successfully. When I stepped through the code, I think it's actually storing it but when I try to access the first team info from my component, I keep getting an empty object which is what I set in initialState. Is it possible that like in the case of setState, the update is not immediate? I added an UPDATE section to my original post with my code.

Comment: "Is it possible that like in the case of setState, the update is not immediate?". No, redux store updates are synchronous. But your action creators, `getTeam` and `getTeamList` are async API calls and only after the promise is resolved (API response), they will invoke their reducer types to update global state. Does this in any way makes sense for the problem you are facing now?

Comment: Further examination shows me that I am in fact executing all the steps and reducing the data into the store BUT it's not happening in time. Looks like I hit the render function of the Team component before the first team data is committed to the store.

Comment: I added a second UPDATE in the original post. Looks like I need a way of controlling the sequence in which actions execute.

Comment: I'm pretty close. I now understand thunks better and use them in my scenario. However, the sequence is still not exactly what I think it should be. I added UPDATE 3. What am I missing? Why am I not getting the sequence I have in mind?

Comment: you're missing a `return` statement before `dispatch(getTeam(teams[0].teamId))`. It should be `return dispatch(getTeam(teams[0].teamId))`.

Comment: Just updated the original post. Is it like that? If so, that didn't work. Still following the same sequence I mentioned.

Comment: Updated the original answer. It should work this time. Let me know after you try it.

Comment: I appreciate your response but looks like it still doesn't follow the correct sequence. As I mentioned in my post, it jumps to isLoading(false) right after isLoading(true). Also, for some reason, I'm also getting inconsistent results as I reload the page. Sometimes team object comes empty even though I make no changes to my code. The minute I put a debugger line in my reducer to see what's going on, everything starts to execute normal again. I remove the debugger line, I may get an empty team object. What could I be doing wrong? Why get inconsistent results? The code should execute the same.

Comment: The sequence issue is still there but I figured out why I was getting inconsistent results. It was due to an unrelated error. Like I said, the sequence is still not right. It still jumps to step 6 from step 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129300/discussion-between-free-soul-and-sam).

Comment: I posted some info and screen shots in the room. Please let me know about your availability so that I can meet you in the chat room. I'm actually adding more steps into that particular action and getting more inconsistent results. I'm definitely making a mistake somewhere.